# Recording Logged in Users on my site through Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

I've a simple site which shows a page after a Registered user logs in the site. The session stores the username and the page is shown.

Now I am trying to store the logged-in username and record it on the Google Analytics showing that this person logged into the site and saw the page.

Google Analytics hopefully should make a table of all the usernames that logged in with the details of each username respectively.

This is what I did:

```
<script>

var user = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'mysite.com');

var dimensionValue = user;

ga('set', 'Logged-user', dimensionValue);

ga('send', 'pageview');


</script>
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working as I am hoping it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax should be

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue); //configure dimension1 in GA-Admin interface of session level
```